# Python-Why the following code is not working-passing dictionary to regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python .i am trying to pass a key value pair from dictionary for replacing string.

```
import re

st ='GET https://example.com/ab/cde/api/v1/Files?page.size=20&page.page=0&page.sort=createdOn%2Cdesc&&_=1483360819974'

di = {'(8a)\w+' : 'uuid','page(.*$)' : 'page' }

for k,v in di.items():
    di_mo = re.sub(k, v, st)
```

But it is not replacing the string

But if i assigned the key and value in variables it is working.

```
v = 'page'
k = 'page(.*$)'
di_mo1 = re.sub(k, v, st)
```

Please help

Comment: It gave me same result for both `dictionary` and assigned key values, can you post your outputs here.

Comment: You probably want to start `di_mo` off as `st` and run replacements on `di_mo` every time, or you’ll lose every replacement except the last one (which could be anything; dicts aren’t ordered).

Comment: What is your final goal? Which substrings from `st` should go in which variables?

Comment: @Arman, for assigned variables iam gettting the expected output i.e GET https://example.com:443/ab/cde/api/v1/Files?page .The expectation is to group all similar calls together and multiple string replacements for all calls in a log file

Comment: I didn't get the solution yet.Can anyone help please